# Nexus RemoteStorageException

Tags: nexus

Short question. Any ideas on the following stack trace in nexus logs?
I could probably find a solution myself, if I even understand what the error was :)

```
ERROR [p21752992-57395] - org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.maven2.M2Repository - Got RemoteStorageException in proxy repository "Maven Public Dependencies" [id=mavenpublicdependencies] while retrieving remote artifact "ResourceStoreRequest(requestPath="/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.16/surefire-junit4-2.16.pom")" from URL groups:public/, this is 1 (re)try, cause: org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.AccessDeniedException: Access denied on repository ID='public', path='/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.16/surefire-junit4-2.16.pom', action='read'!
```

Comment: Seems like an access rights issue. Did you get this sorted?

Comment: Yeah, but was upgrading nexus anyway, so who knows what it really was.

Comment: You should probably remove the question then.. or add an answer that upgrade solved the issue although it might have just masked the actual fix.